# How to bind to a property of another object in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I want to do something like this:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=MyObject.Property}" />
```

And I would like it to be changed when `MyObject` will be assigned to another `Object` (`Property` remains the same)

How to do it properly?

Comment: Your binding Source (I.E the `DataContext` of this label) must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` properly.

Comment: Will it be enough that my class will notify about change of `MyObject` (which is a property)? Will the label's content binded to `MyObject.Property` update automatically when I change `MyObject`?

Comment: Yes. Have you tried it?

Comment: No, I thought that the Label will remain binded to an old object. I will try it in a moment

Comment: Yes, it's working just fine :) Sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

Use ElementName in your binding.

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=myTextBox, Path=Text}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

follow following steps:

inherit INotifyPropertyChanged

```
 public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int customerID;

        public int CustomerID
        {
            get { return customerID; }
            set { customerID = value; OnPropertyChanged("CustomerID"); }
        }
```

set datacontext and bid like below

```
<Label Content="{Binding Property, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

**second method:**
use element binding:

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=Combo, Path=Text}" Binding path="Property" />
```